# Использование прокси в zombie.js

Tags: php, javascript, node.js, curl

Здравствуйте! Я не очень разбираюсь в JS и только начал работать с node.js. Решил попробовать zombie.js для парсинга страниц. Сделал скрипт - вроде работает. Решил попробовать с использованием прокси по аналогии с curl в php. Но вот незадача - задаю proxy для browser , но при выводе полученной страницы выводит локальный IP адрес сервера, а не другой, как при использовании proxy в curl php. Прокси проверял с помощью curl и выбирал элитные, которые выдают другой IP. Кто-то сможет помочь. А то чувствую, что штука интересная, а вот использовать не могу. Вот мой код:

```
var zombie = require('zombie');
var fs = require('fs');

var startURL = 'http://google.ru';

var proxy = 'http://46.101.59.22:8118';
var userAgent = 'Mozilla/5.0 Chrome/10.0.613.0 Safari/534.15';

const browser = new zombie({waitDuration: 29*1000,proxy: proxy,userAgent: userAgent});

var b64 = 'Ноутбук ASUS X541SA-XX119T';

zombie.proxy = proxy;
zombie.userAgent = userAgent;

    zombie.visit(startUrl,function(err,browser){

       browser.fill('input[name="q"]', b64);

       browser.pressButton('.btnK', function(){
        console.log(browser);
            fs.writeFileSync('out.html', browser.html());

        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Добрый. Заинтересовался вашим вопросом. Я использую *5.0.7* версию пакета zombie, и данный код у меня работает корректно. Ваша проблема может заключаться вот в чем: либо вы используете прокси, которые содержат информацию о вашем ip адресе, либо вы используете версию zombie, где есть этот баг, и вам необходимо переустановить этот пакет.

Comment: У меня та же версия zombie и скрипт конечно рабочий. Попробуйте изменить адрес google.ru на 2ip.ru или другой сервис по определению входящего IP и посмотрите, какой ip будет возвращать сервис. Я тестирую на собственном скрипте по определению IP. Не стал его указывать, т.к. он черновой, а все прочие сервисы возвращали пустую страницу возможно из-за black-листа адреса прокси для ресурсов. Поэтому указал google.ru

Comment: Еще одно уточнение. Сейчас попробовал на сервисе http://phpfaq.ru/tech/ip. Действительно выдает другой IP. Т.е. прокси срабатывает, но думается он не срабатывает про нажатии какой-либо кнопки (pressButton), т.е даже при задании прокси при нажатии прокси сбрасывается или не учитывается при переходе по адресу после нажатия кнопки.